# Where to store HTML snippets for a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension that will inject small snippets of HTML into a page. The extension is basically nothing more than a content script which inserts HTML.

Now some of the pieces of HTML are quite large, so building them all from scratch in JavaScript is an option, but not preferred. Working with strings in my content is also an option, but I have the idea it will get messy.

Best way IMO opinion is to have a separate file with HTML blocks and have my content script pick one of the blocks depending on the users action. My question is now if the chrome extension has such a functionality.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Sorry I don't think you understand the question. I need to store them within my extensions file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in a background page and pass messages from the content script to the background page to grab the html blocks in question and pass them back via a callback function.

in the content script

```
function grabHTML(blockId) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'get-html': blockId },insertHTML);
}
function insertHTML (blockId,HTML) { 
   /* your insertion logic goes here */ 
}
```

In background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request['get-html']) {
     var HTMLel = document.getElementById(request['get-html']);
     if (HTMLel) {
       sendResponse(request['get-html'],HTMLel.innerHTML);
     }
  }
});
```

And in your backgound.html

```
<html>
  <head><script src="background.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <div id="block-1"> ... </div>
    <div id="block-2"> ... </div>

    <div id="block-n"> ... </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I saw it a little late. Do you know if there any benefits of choosing this method over the AJAX implementation.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I'd assume the main benefit would be speed, as the HTML snippets would already in memory and you wouldn't need to deal with calls to the file system.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the HTML in separate file(s), and then use ajax to read the data from those files. You can also store multiple blocks of HTML in a single file, read the file via ajax, and then use a regexp to extract the desired block.

Comment: Yeah i'm just looking at the option right now. I wonder if there is no internal way to read the files instead of doing an ajax call.

Comment: It would seem not. the `chrome.fileSystem` API only supports reading files which the user manually selects via `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`